# Reduce - split into multiple batch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out how do I split `Batch` into groups. For example `res` should return two Batch of of `F` and `G`.

```
var data = {
    Items: [{
        ItemId: "222",
        Sum: 2,
        Batch: "F"
    }, {
        ItemId: "222",
        Sum: 2,
        Batch: "F"
    }, {
        ItemId: "333",
        Sum: 3,
        Batch: "G"
    }, {
        ItemId: "333",
        Sum: 5,
        Batch: "F"
    }, ]
};

var res = data.Items.reduce((acc,obj)=>{
    var existObj = acc.find(item=>item.Id === obj.ItemId);

    if (existObj) {
        existObj.Sum += obj.Sum;

        return acc;
    }

    acc.push({
        Id: obj.ItemId,
        Sum: obj.Sum
    });

    return acc;
}
, []);
```

Currently it output like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "222",
    "Sum": 4
  },
  {
    "Id": "333",
    "Sum": 8
  }
]
```

The logic above, if the ItemId is exist in the object, it will add `Sum`. It has combined ItemId to remove duplication.

It should split to batches and take Sum into account base on `Batch`. For example expected output something like this:

```
{
  "Batch": [
    {
      "BatchName": "F",
      "Lines": [
        {
          "Id": "222",
          "Sum": 4
        },
        {
          "Id": "333",
          "Sum": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "BatchName": "G",
      "Lines": [
        {
          "Id": "333",
          "Sum": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: structure don't need to be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should get you what you need

```js
var tmp = data.Items.reduce((a,{ItemId, Sum, Batch})=>{
   a[Batch] = a[Batch] || {}
   a[Batch][ItemId] = a[Batch][ItemId] || {ItemId, Sum:0}
   a[Batch][ItemId].Sum += Sum
   return a;

},{});

var res = Object.keys(tmp)
      .reduce((a,k)=> a.concat({BatchName: k, Lines: Object.values(tmp[k])}),[])
      
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
var data = {
    Items: [{
        ItemId: "222",
        Sum: 2,
        Batch: "F"
    }, {
        ItemId: "222",
        Sum: 2,
        Batch: "F"
    }, {
        ItemId: "333",
        Sum: 3,
        Batch: "G"
    }, {
        ItemId: "333",
        Sum: 5,
        Batch: "F"
    }, ]
};

</script>
```

Comment: What does `a[Batch] = a[Batch] || {}` mean?

Comment: It means if that property doesn't exist make it an empty object. Will see better if you add `console.log(tmp)`

Comment: Ah, so it mean like this in other way? `a[Batch] = (a[Batch])? a[Batch] : {};`

Comment: Yes...is basically the same but I use an `||` which is OR

Comment: Are you be able to add another solution like my way in the topic? I used find and push.

Comment: Is more efficient to create the object and it certainly produces expected results

Comment: Could use 2 finds....one to find the batch...then another to find the id. But since find has to iterate arrays using a single object is very efficient and then is a simple iteration of that object to produce final results

Comment: Thank you very much. From your first example, you are using `a[Batch]` - why can't we do `a.Batch` ? for example `a.Batch = a.Batch || {}`

Comment: Because Batch is a variable created from destructured object. Is same as doing `reduce((a,c)=>{ a[c.Batch]....` but with less code to write See https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/